# jquery ui themeswitcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

hello i use themeswitcher jquery ui but now no work.

mi code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/themeswitchertool/"></script>

            $('#switcher').themeswitcher({
                 onSelect: function() {
                    $.cookie('hola',$.cookie('jquery-ui-theme'),{ expires: 7 });
                    //alert($.cookie('jquery-ui-theme'));
                 },
                 path:'/web/'
                 ,initialText: "Seleccione tema"
                 ,loadTheme: "Smoothness"
                 ,buttonPreText: "Tema: "
                });
```

I think the direction does not work.

widget not exists?

someone could help me? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

jqueryUI.com has just completely redone their website.  The themeswitcher tool no longer exists.  I think that until they get their stuff straight over there, you are out of luck.

Other people are complaining about this issue [here.](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-plugin-themeswitcher-no-longer-works).

According to their [twitter feed](https://twitter.com/jqueryui) the themeswitcher is "no more".  But there is always [the Super Theme Switcher.](https://github.com/harborhoffer/Super-Theme-Switcher)